# ssh connection keep disconected , how to find way? in CentOs vmware

Tags: linux-networking

i have CentOS installed on vmware , few days ago every thing was working fine.
today every time im connect with putty to the CentOs server after few minutes 
it disconnect me , how can i find what is the reason  ?

when i check /var/log/secure im getting :

Jan 23 18:01:09 localhost sshd[17461]: Exiting on signal 15
when i check the "/var/log/messages" there is nothing that says something about this signal
my iptables is closed

Comment: Try to see if the connection remains up when you connect from/to the same machine but using a different router.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following line to the /etc/ssh/ssh_config file:

```
ServerAliveInterval 60
```

The number is the amount of seconds before the server with send the no-op code.

Comment: well i did it then restarted the server checked to see if sshd is up with netstat -tulpn , and i see its listening , but now i can't even connect to the server .
also stoped the iptables

Comment: You shouldn't have to restart the server after changes to `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, it's the configuration for the client. Are you sure you edited `ssh_config` instead of `sshd_config`?

Comment: ha ok , yeah i edit the ssh_config in the end of the file

Comment: The `ssh_config` file would be if you're sshing *from* Linux.  The matching setting in putty is on the `Connection` screen, `Seconds between keepalives`

Comment: i updated my question

Answer (score 0):

A signal 15 in the log indicates something more serious then just a timeout issue.

I would run `strace -p PID` for the sshd process and see why it's actually dieing.

You should also try ssh from the server to localhost and see if that's stable. For example: `ssh root@0`

Definitely you should install any available CentOS upgrades as well. If the problems persist, then try reinstall the SSH server package in case it's been compromised or corrupted somehow.